# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (90742,1) into shape (240742,1)

Tags: python, time-series, lstm

I have encountered a `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (90742,1) into shape (240742,1).`

Here is my code:

```
# shift train predictions for plotting 
train_predict_plot = np.empty_like(data)
train_predict_plot[:, :] np.nan
train_predict_plot[lags:len(train_predict)+lags, :] = train_predict

# shift test predictions for plotting
test_predict_plot = np.empty_like(data)
test_predict_plot[:, :] = np.nan
test_predict_plot[len(train_predict) + (lags * 2)+1:len(data)-1, :] = test_predict

# plot observation and predictions 
plt.plot(data, label='Observed', color='#006699'); 
plt.plot(train_predict_plot, label='Prediction for Train Set', color='#006699', alpha=0.5); 
plt.plot(test_predict_plot, label='Prediction for Test Set', color='#ff0066'); 
plt.legend(loc='upper left') 
plt.title('LSTM Recurrent Neural Net') 
plt.show()
```

Here is the error:

[image: ValueError]

I have looked at the previous questions but they are all different. Would someone please tell me how to fix this problem specifically in my case? Thank you very much.

Comment: You should really post your code inside your question and format it properly instead of just posting an image. People are much more inclined to help you that way.

Comment: what is the shape of data?
I think length of data is smaller than length of train which is why it is throwing error.
check by `len(data)` and `len(train_predict)`

Comment: And how have you defined `lags`?

Comment: @rahlf23 hi i tried posting my code... but there was indentation error. I will try to fix that later. 
I followed the Time Series with LSTM code on this website: http://dacatay.com/data-science/part-6-time-series-prediction-neural-networks-python/
Yes , lags=3
Thanks for the reply,

Comment: @UpasanaMittal 
Hi, yes 
data.shape (315746, 1)
train_predict.shape (74996, 1)

Comment: Post your code and people can help with the indentation errors if they exist, but you should really post all the code necessary to reproduce your issue (i.e. all the variables needed)

Comment: @rahlf23 I tried posting all my codes but i am not allowed to submit my edits because my post mostly code, it wants me to add something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `test_predict.shape` must be `(90742,1)` The error you are facing because of `test_predict_plot[240742,:]=test_predict` this input here.

Shape of `test_predict_plot[75003:315745,:]` becomes `(240742,1)` and input an array of shorter or different shape than this will throw error.

I tried to reproduce the error by running the code provided in the link by you, but there was no error as:
`len(train_predict)=116`, `len(data)=144` and `len(test_predict)=20` which goes with the calculation very well of the code. By calculation I mean here in this line of code:

```
    test_predict_plot[len(train_predict)+(lags*2)+1:len(data)-1, :] = test_predict
```

which will become:

```
    test_predict_plot[116+6+1:144-1, :] = test_predict
```

So you need to do the changes in the code such that lengths of input matches.
You can also try by this change in code:

```
    test_predict_plot[<len(test_predict)>, :] = test_predict
```

***Solution***

Found the problem:

```
    train = dataset[150000:225000, :]
    test = dataset[225000:, :]
```

You need to do changes here:

```
    train_predict_plot = np.empty_like(data[150000:, :])
    train_predict_plot[:, :] = np.nan
    train_predict_plot[lags: len(train_predict) + lags, :] = train_predict

    # shift test predictions for plotting
    test_predict_plot = np.empty_like(data[150000:, :])
    test_predict_plot[:, :] = np.nan
    test_predict_plot[len(train_predict)+(lags*2)+1:len(data[150000:, :])-1, :] = test_predict
```

Comment: I don't understand yet. How can let you take a look at my full codes?

Comment: @mattcoder79 I have edited the answer. are you able to understand now?

Comment: @mattcoder79 if you can push your code to git then let me know.

Comment: @mattcoder79 Found the problem:
       `train = dataset[150000:225000, :]
        test = dataset[225000:, :]`

You need to do changes here:
`train_predict_plot = np.empty_like(data[150000:, :])
train_predict_plot[:, :] = np.nan
train_predict_plot[lags: len(train_predict) + lags, :] = train_predict

# shift test predictions for plotting
test_predict_plot = np.empty_like(data[150000:, :])
test_predict_plot[:, :] = np.nan
test_predict_plot[len(train_predict)+(lags*2)+1:len([150000:, :])-1, :] = test_predict`